# Which Python special methods bypass the object's `__getattribute__` on lookup?

Tags: python, getattribute

Which Python special methods bypass the object's `__getattribute__` on lookup?  See [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, then the answer is probably *all of them* since special methods are not real members of the instances.

Comment: @poke If you're sure, please add an answer.

Comment: That document seems pretty clear, but you're obviously trying to relate it to some problem.  Do you have more context?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: It wasn't clear to me, but I guess looking at it again it is all of them as poke said.  I'm not solving a problem; just reading the docs for fun!

Comment: Good on you!  There were some arcane corner cases there relating to metaclasses, and of course if you try to set x.__len__ in an instance, that won't work.  That's why I asked...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: what are the corner cases with metaclasses?

Comment: Look in the doc where it says "implicit special method lookup generally..."  Generally is a nice weasel word that says even the doc-writer doesn't know if it always happens, e.g. maybe it doesn't for `__lt__` or something...  But in any case, as you can see in that example, an explicit `__len__` lookup is different than `len()` when the metaclass is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As poke says, the answer is for all methods.